# Changing from WEBrick to Unicorn: Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, webrick

I'm trying to deploy on Heroku. I'm not looking for a solution but for a few REALLY REALLY GOOD hints at what might be wrong. My app deploys just fine locally via WEBrick at localhost. Thanks in advance for paying it forward!

## HEROKU PS

```
$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
web.1: up 2014/05/01 19:10:07 (~ 40m ago)
```

## PROCFILE

`web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb`

## CONFIG/UNICORN

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

## LOGS

```
$ heroku logs --tail
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669826+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669827+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669829+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669830+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669831+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669833+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.670528+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:06:28] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-01T22:06:28.722380+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-05-01T22:06:28.722384+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25341
2014-05-01T22:06:28.722386+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-05-01T22:06:28.722387+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-05-01T22:06:28.722389+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-05-01T22:06:28.670730+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:06:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669797+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:06:28] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-01T22:06:28.722390+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669823+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669805+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669825+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669803+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669809+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669808+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669811+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-05-01T22:06:28.669812+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:06:32.467872+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:06:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-05-01T22:06:32.467943+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:06:32] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
2014-05-01T22:06:32.468669+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:06:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=34260
2014-05-01T22:06:28.411657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 34260 -e production`
2014-05-01T22:06:32.855198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-01T22:06:30.286552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-05-01T22:08:18.068610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=4dc3fb9c-cde0-46a5-88f2-db362cc9eee1 fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1027ms status=500 bytes=1754
2014-05-01T22:09:08.648293+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake -T` by user@email.com
2014-05-01T22:09:12.102177+00:00 heroku[run.4887]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-01T22:09:11.963908+00:00 heroku[run.4887]: Awaiting client
2014-05-01T22:09:12.020918+00:00 heroku[run.4887]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake -T`
2014-05-01T22:09:15.365420+00:00 heroku[run.4887]: Process exited with status 0
2014-05-01T22:09:15.382709+00:00 heroku[run.4887]: State changed from up to complete
2014-05-01T22:17:47.110019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=9750c596-2533-49d5-b1c7-7c11a358482b fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1754
2014-05-01T22:33:53+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-01T22:34:51+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-05-01T22:34:51.243934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-05-01T22:34:51.094619+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e9716a6 by user@email.com
2014-05-01T22:34:51.094733+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by user@email.com
2014-05-01T22:34:54.836776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 56274 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-05-01T22:34:58.799486+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T22:34:58.799341 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:56274 fd=10
2014-05-01T22:34:58.903898+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T22:34:58.903421 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2014-05-01T22:34:58.933286+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T22:34:58.932920 #11]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2014-05-01T22:34:59.060518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-01T22:34:58.884743+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T22:34:58.883328 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2014-05-01T22:34:58.923851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T22:34:58.923517 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798802+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798805+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798789+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:36:07] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798797+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798799+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798800+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798804+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798807+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798808+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798810+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798812+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798813+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798815+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798817+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798818+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798824+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:36:07] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-01T22:36:07.798852+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-01 22:36:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-01T22:36:07.836340+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-05-01T22:36:07.836345+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:34260
2014-05-01T22:36:07.836347+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-05-01T22:36:07.836350+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-05-01T22:36:07.836351+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-05-01T22:36:07.836353+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-01T22:36:07.016924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-01T22:36:09.488916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-05-01T22:37:57.660165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=8bec6646-db68-46eb-af61-f1a1a4875ef0 fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=232ms status=500 bytes=1741
2014-05-01T22:57:26.291104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=7062c729-d951-4e7e-bdd1-6796033f13cb fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=110ms status=500 bytes=1741
2014-05-01T23:01:28+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-01T23:01:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-05-01T23:01:55.044753+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d4794ad by user@email.com
2014-05-01T23:01:55.044822+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by user@email.com
2014-05-01T23:01:55.175625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-05-01T23:02:00.910314+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:02:00.910164 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-05-01T23:02:02.729124+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:02:02.728995 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:30305 fd=10
2014-05-01T23:02:02.922640+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:02:02.922268 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2014-05-01T23:02:02.945369+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:02:02.945130 #11]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2014-05-01T23:02:02.942966+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:02:02.942697 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2014-05-01T23:02:02.888714+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:02:02.888142 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2014-05-01T23:02:03.165076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-01T23:03:42.322419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-01T23:03:42.956542+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-05-01T23:03:42.972448+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2014-05-01T23:03:42.956243+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-05-01T23:03:42.958048+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-05-01T23:03:43.205441+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:03:43.204928 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2014-05-01T23:03:43.205564+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:03:43.205502 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2014-05-01T23:03:43.512190+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:03:43.512038 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11 exit 0> worker=2
2014-05-01T23:03:43.512417+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-01T23:03:43.512294 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2014-05-01T23:03:44.847319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-05-01T23:04:06.218998+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=a016613c-b23a-4c77-9929-db1e393b4b1c fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=455ms status=500 bytes=1741
2014-05-01T23:16:55.994478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=4dae8b3f-4062-43e9-a93c-a7c84bb2e9f1 fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=287ms status=500 bytes=1741
2014-05-01T23:57:38.927274+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=66fbef35-faba-484d-8c36-3cda398b1a02 fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=1741
2014-05-02T00:09:32+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-02T00:09:59.606262+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 46baea2 by user@email.com
2014-05-02T00:09:59.606262+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by user@email.com
2014-05-02T00:09:59+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-05-02T00:09:59.784380+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-05-02T00:10:04.198799+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-05-02T00:10:04.198830+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-05-02T00:10:04.199082+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT
2014-05-02T00:10:04.199185+00:00 app[web.1]: Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
2014-05-02T00:10:04.247516+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:04.247380 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2014-05-02T00:10:04.720959+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:04.720572 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2014-05-02T00:10:04.821857+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:04.821716 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 11 exit 0> worker=2
2014-05-02T00:10:04.721313+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:04.721042 #2]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2014-05-02T00:10:04.822045+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:04.821978 #2]  INFO -- : master complete
2014-05-02T00:10:06.016890+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:06.016769 #2]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:16760 fd=10
2014-05-02T00:10:06.185581+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:06.185151 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2014-05-02T00:10:06.209693+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:06.209050 #11]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
2014-05-02T00:10:06.163461+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:06.162863 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2014-05-02T00:10:06.199971+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-05-02T00:10:06.199593 #2]  INFO -- : master process ready
2014-05-02T00:10:06.291060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-02T00:10:02.947512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 16760 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2014-05-02T00:10:03.360386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-02T00:10:06.307630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-05-02T00:10:16.115213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=be3c48e4-8bac-438f-95de-348dd8b564f5 fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=134ms status=500 bytes=1741
2014-05-02T00:11:52.927726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=morning-thirst-9105.herokuapp.com request_id=99db05de-a595-4aa5-89e0-074c152b3595 fwd="58.919.9.196" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=1741
^C
 !    Command cancelled.
```

## GEMS

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.0, 4.0.1)
actionpack (4.1.0, 4.0.1)
actionview (4.1.0)
activemodel (4.1.0, 4.0.4, 4.0.1, 3.2.14, 3.2.12)
activerecord (4.1.0, 4.0.4, 4.0.1, 3.2.14, 3.2.12)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.1.0, 4.0.4, 4.0.1, 3.2.14, 3.2.12)
addressable (2.3.5)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 5.0.0, 4.0.2, 4.0.1, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.16, 1.1.14)
backports (3.6.0, 3.3.3, 3.3.1, 2.6.1)
bcrypt (3.1.7)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bond (0.4.3)
bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
capybara (2.2.1)
childprocess (0.5.3)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
coveralls (0.7.0)
cucumber (1.3.10)
daemons (1.1.9)
diff-lcs (1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.1, 1.1.3)
docile (1.1.3)
dotenv (0.7.0)
em-synchrony (1.0.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.3, 1.0.0)
excon (0.25.3)
execjs (2.0.2)
factory_girl (4.4.0)
faker (1.3.0, 1.1.2)
faye-websocket (0.7.2)
ffi (1.9.3)
foreman (0.67.0)
gherkin (2.12.2)
given_core (3.5.0)
heroku (3.1.0)
heroku-api (0.3.15)
hike (1.2.3)
hiredis (0.5.2)
i18n (0.6.9, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.1)
jbuilder (2.0.6)
jquery-rails (3.1.0)
json (1.8.1)
kgio (2.9.2)
launchy (2.4.2)
mail (2.5.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (2.0, 1.25.1, 1.25)
mini_portile (0.5.3, 0.5.2)
minitest (5.3.3, 5.3.2, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.9.3, 1.9.2, 1.8.2, 1.8.0, 1.7.3, 1.6.1)
multi_test (0.0.3)
netrc (0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.6.1)
oauth (0.4.7)
pg (0.17.1, 0.17.0, 0.15.1, 0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.4, 0.3.3)
pry (0.9.12.6)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-protection (1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.1.0, 4.0.1)
rails_12factor (0.0.2)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
railties (4.1.0, 4.0.1)
raindrops (0.13.0)
rake (10.3.1, 10.3.0, 10.2.2, 10.1.0, 10.0.4, 10.0.3)
rdoc (4.1.1, 4.0.1)
redis (3.0.7)
redis-objects (0.9.1)
rest-client (1.6.7)
ripl (0.7.0)
ripl-multi_line (0.3.1)
ripl-rack (0.2.0)
rspec (2.14.1, 2.13.0, 2.12.0)
rspec-collection_matchers (0.0.4)
rspec-core (3.0.0.beta2, 2.14.8, 2.14.7, 2.14.3, 2.13.1, 2.12.2, 2.12.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.0.beta2, 2.14.5, 2.14.4, 2.14.0, 2.13.0, 2.12.1, 2.12.0)
rspec-given (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.0.0.beta2, 2.14.6, 2.14.4, 2.14.1, 2.13.1, 2.13.0, 2.12.2, 2.12.0)
rspec-rails (3.0.0.beta2, 2.14.2)
rspec-support (3.0.0.beta2)
rubygems-update (2.1.10)
rubyzip (1.1.3, 1.1.0)
sass (3.2.19)
sass-rails (4.0.3)
sdoc (0.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.41.0)
shotgun (0.9)
shoulda-matchers (2.6.1, 2.6.0)
simplecov (0.8.2)
simplecov-html (0.8.0)
sinatra (1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.3.6, 1.3.4, 1.1.0)
sinatra-activerecord (1.2.3)
sinatra-contrib (1.4.2, 1.4.0, 1.3.1)
sinatra-flash (0.3.0)
sinatra-redirect-with-flash (0.2.0)
slop (3.5.0)
sorcerer (1.0.2)
spring (1.1.2)
sprockets (2.11.0, 2.10.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3, 2.0.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.9, 1.3.7)
term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
thin (1.6.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0)
thor (0.19.1, 0.18.1, 0.17.0)
thread_safe (0.3.3, 0.3.1, 0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.5, 1.3.3)
tins (1.1.0)
treetop (1.4.15)
turbolinks (2.2.2)
tux (0.3.0)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
twurl (0.9.1)
tzinfo (1.1.0, 0.3.39, 0.3.38, 0.3.37, 0.3.35)
uglifier (2.5.0)
unicorn (4.8.2)
websocket (1.0.7)
websocket-driver (0.3.2)
websocket-rails (0.7.0)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs and follow the instructions is what I believe I was missing, completely forgot to migrate. Deployed now.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we use to run Unicorn on Heroku, perhaps it will help you:

```
#ProcFile
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb

#config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes 3
preload_app true
timeout 30

#Gemfile
group :production do
    gem 'unicorn'
end
```

Hopefully this will help you out